# VBA find the name of last folder

Tags: vba, excel

How can I code a function in VBA that helps me to get the last folder(example: Thisfolder) before the file .

```
P:\Folder1\..\Thisfolder\Test.txt
```

I want to just extract : Thisfolder

Comment: are you looking to find the last folder of the open excel file where you want this code ?

Comment: @ShaiRado 
 
i want to write it in a cell like : thisworkbook.worksheets("This").cells(1,1)="The name of the last folder"

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 8, accepted):

not tested, quickly written here but you get the idea:

```
function GetRightFolder(fname) as string
    dim a
    a = split(fname, "\")
    getRightFolder = a(ubound(a)-1)
end function
```

Answer (score 2):

I included a function to get the files parent folder name and one to get it's path

- getParentFolderPath("P:\Folder1..\Thisfolder\Test.txt") : P:\Folder1..\Thisfolder
- getParentFolderName("P:\Folder1..\Thisfolder\Test.txt") : Thisfolder

---

```
Function getParentFolderPath(BasePath As String)
    getParentFolderPath = Left(BasePath, InStrRev(BasePath, "\") - 1)
End Function

Function getParentFolderName(BasePath As String)
    BasePath = Left(BasePath, InStrRev(BasePath, "\") - 1)
    getParentFolderName = Right(BasePath, Len(BasePath) - InStrRev(BasePath, "\"))
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code that will put the name of `ThisWorkbook` last folder (from full path) in **Cell A1** in sheet "***This***".

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetLastFolderName()

Dim LastFolder                  As String
Dim FullPath                    As String
Dim c                           As Long

FullPath = ThisWorkbook.Path

c = InStrRev(FullPath, "\")
LastFolder = Right(FullPath, Len(FullPath) - c)

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("This").Cells(1, 1) = LastFolder

End Sub
```